# When I use a controller method with a verb HTTP Post the controller use other method with the same name without a verb C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC project that involves integrating a Rest API. I'm encountering an issue where I have two methods in my controller with the same name, but different HTTP verbs assigned to them. However, when I execute the program, it seems to be using the method without the HTTP verb annotation, whereas I intend to use the method with the specific verb.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm dealing with in my controller:

```
 // GET: NormUserController/Details/5
 public IActionResult Details(BankAccount account)
 {
     if (account != null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("con" + account.IdUser);
         return View(account);
     }

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int IdAccount)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("starting post");
     var account = await servicio_APIBAccount.Obtener(IdAccount);
     Console.WriteLine("Account: " +  account.IdAccount);

     if (account != null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Id Account " + account.IdAccount);
         return View("Edit", account);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Failed");

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

This is the razor view where I'm trying to use the method with the verb annotation:

```
@model BankAccount

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Estado de cuenta";
}

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

<<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Cuenta de ahorro</h4>
        <table class="table table-borderless">
            <tr>
                <td>Número de cuenta:</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Model.AccountNumber</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Saldo disponible:</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>$@Model.AccountAmount</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="NormUser" class="button button-accion">Transferencias</a>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" class="button cerrar-sesion">Cerrar Sesión</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mix up the annotations? GET doesn't have a body while it would make little sense to use a POST that accepts just a number

Comment: Your Razor view doesn't have any forms either. The `Details` link will issue a GET.